# If Row "L" contains ANY value, return the letter "V" in Row D

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new using VBA and macros in Excel and am still working my way through problems. I will say that I have found this site to be the best help available. I think the problem I am having is a simple one but cannot figure out where to start.

I want to return the letter "V" in column D if column P contains ANY value... ie - P1 has a letter in it.. return a "V" to D1. Column P will be populated with an early sub()

Thanks!

Comment: **Row D** or **Column D** ??

Comment: in D1: `=IF(P1<>"","V","")` then copy down.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub PlaceV()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("P:P")).Cells
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(r.Row, "D").Value = "V"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student! That is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up using r.Row +1 to bypass the row of headers.

Comment: @Rmoore, if you did that, then you are off by one row between column P and column D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would have to use VBA for this kind of problem, there is an out-of-the box excel function which checks if a cell is empty or not. You can just combine this with an If-Statement to put out a "V" in the column depending on wether there is a value in another column. If you want to check cells one by one cou can use "IS BLANK". If you want to check several cells at once you can go for COUNTA together with the size of the range you want to check.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the suggestion. Unfortunately, we send our spreadsheets off to an asset management team that uploads them into databases. The databases can't accept spreadsheets with formulas embedded.